# Can a Flash executable file be used for SCORM?

Tags: flash, actionscript, scorm

A client's just asked if a Flash-based training tool I created a few years ago can be made SCORM-compliant. The tool is very image-heavy and is therefore usually held on the user's PC, rather than being hosted online.

I know that an SWF file on an HTML page definitely can fit the bill, but is it possible to do the same using a Flash executable (EXE) file with web access, and without any HTML? The training tool is designed to run as a full-screen application and my client would want it to stay that way if at all possible (i.e. not in a browser window).

Comment: Dorian, do you mean an AIR desktop app ?

Comment: No, it's just a straightforward Flash file output as a standalone Win projector (.exe). There's also no budget to do anything other than adding SCORM to it, or if that's not possible, exporting it as an SWF with SCORM compliance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't, you need a SWF to use Flash content in SCORM.

Maybe your option is use a decompiler program (only if you are the owner of the copyrights)

Comment: Thanks - I was afraid that was the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you can trade SCORM for TinCan, you can achieve what you're looking for. SCORM is designed for object to be run from within the LMS, while TinCan supports external communication, so you can send usage data from EXE over web to the LMS.